# find specific number in array for if statement

Tags: javascript

I know there are alot of questions like this on here but they keep pointing me to using `includes` and that is not working for me for some reason.

**Goal** - use an if statement to find out if a number exists in an array. (Don't care if its jQuery or plan JS)

I tried using includes but that failed:

```
testdata = [1,256]
testdata.includes(1) #or testdata.includes(256)
\\false
```

[image]

I also tried using `indexof` but that failed too:

```
testdata = [1,256]
testdata.indexOf('256') >= 0
\\false
```

[image]

Comment: There's something fishy here, as cheesyMan points out - `testdata` has length `1` because it is an array inside an array.  You actually seem to have: `testdata = [ [1, 256] ]`

Comment: At first I didn't understand what @cheesyMan meant but after reading your comment with the double brackets I relized what happened. Hahaha, I didn't realize the array was inside an array. I'll give him the credit. Thanks for clearing up his answer for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it looks like your array `[1,256]` is the first element of `testdata` array. In fact, you can see that `testdata` length is 1.

You should check if `testdata[0].includes(1)`

Comment: At first I didn't understand what you meant but after reading @wyck's comment I understand what you mean. You get the credit on this one. Thanks for the clearup!

Answer (score 1):

Your array is numbers but your `.indexOf` argument is a string.

The snippet below works fine.

If you need true/false, use a conditional block like:

```
let numberFound = false;

if (testdata.indexOf(256)>-1) {
  numberFound = true;
 } else {
  numberFound = false;
 }
```

Instead of the full if/else block, it is more usual to condense the conditional using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

like this:

```
numberFound = (testdata.indexOf(256) > -1) ? true : false)
```

finally, if you're testing several entries, use a function to return `true/false` depending on what was passed to it:

```
function numberFound(number,array) {
  return (array.indexOf(number) > -1) ? true : false;
}
```

I've amended the snippet:

```js
const testdata = [1,256]
console.log(testdata.indexOf(256));

console.log("test for 25: ", (testdata.indexOf(25) > -1) ? true : false);

console.log("test for 56: ", (testdata.indexOf(56) > -1) ? true : false);

console.log("test for 256: ", (testdata.indexOf(256) > -1) ? true : false);

function numberFound(number,array) {
  return (array.indexOf(number) > -1) ? true : false;
}

console.log("function testing 256:", numberFound(256,testdata));

console.log("function testing 25:", numberFound(25,testdata));
```

Comment: Further info: `Array.prototype.indexOf` compares elements using strict equality (see the [note about strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#description) in the docs).

Comment: I think I will just have to delete this question and ask again. This doesn't help me know if 256 is in an array. I probably just asked for the wrong thing. I tried your code and it doesn't give me a true or false to know if 256 is in the array. `if (testdata.indexOf('256')){console.log("true")}` is the same as `if (testdata.indexOf('56')){console.log("true")}`. It will always print true.

Comment: @PythonKiddieScripterX, are you absolutely certain you have `[1, 256]` because we're pretty sure you have `[[ 1, 256 ]]`

Comment: I've amended the snippet to include returning true/false. I have no idea what the discussion about [[ 1, 256 ]] is, it's not in your question nor my answer and is irrelevant to your original problem (which was soley caused by presenting the number as a string. And no, neither 25, nor 56 are found when searching for 256 `indexOf` matches the element not sub-parts of it. Hope the new snippet is clearer for you.

Comment: @PythonKiddieScripterX the reason `(testdata.indexOf('56')){console.log("true")}` logs true is because, `indexOf(anything not present)` will return -1, a number that exists, not `false` (or even, in this case `falsy` (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). IndexOf never returns `false`.

Answer (score -2):

It is not working for you because you use it in the wrong way. `#` is the private identifier in JS. If you use `//` instead it works.

```js
testdata = [1,256];

console.log(testdata.includes(1)); // or testdata.includes(256)
```